# Javascript/jQuery auto submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Working on a 3rd party js script for Slate and need to switch the line `form.on('submit', function()`  to have the submit button fire automatically. I don't need user clicking on submit button.
It looks like `form.on('submit', function()`  is a mouse click event to click the submit button?
I need to integrate the below with `$('#myForm').submit();` somehow I suspect. Can you integrate `FW.Lazy.Commit(this, { cmd: 'submit' });` in `$('#myForm').submit();` to achieve the functionality?

This works for manual submit:

```
<script async="async">  /*<![CDATA[*/
    $( document ).ready(function() {
              var form = $('#myForm');
              form.on('submit', function() 
                  FW.Lazy.Commit(this, { 
                  cmd: 'submit' 
                  }); 
              ); 
    })(FW.$);
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Submit HTML

```
<form id="myForm"...>
 <button class="default form_button_submit" id="mySubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This didn't work for me

```
 <script async="async">  /*<![CDATA[*/
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            
            $('#myForm').submit(function() 

             FW.Lazy.Commit(this, 
                   { 
                    cmd: 'submit' 
                   } ); 
             );

    })(FW.$);
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far? Have you confirmed the function is even firing on page load (e.g. `console.log('function triggered');`)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE is what you're looking for, so `(function () { $("#form_2c33247d").submit(); })();` should do it in vanilla JS. But it also looks like you're using another library `FW` and are trying to do additional things after the form is submitted. Please add more details to your question explaining what this is doing.

Comment: Your first few attempts using `form.on('submit', function() { ... });` are adding event listeners that will trigger when the form is submitted, but it's not triggering the form to submit. Similarly, per https://api.jquery.com/submit/ if you do `$(...).submit()` it _triggers_ the submit event, but `$(...).submit(function() {...});` adds an event listener (like your first few examples are doing) that will trigger when the form is submitted.

Comment: Slight correction to my IIFE comment - because you're using jQuery (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), `$( document ).ready(function() { $("#form_2c33247d").submit(); });` should be correct.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't want the submit button to be clicked on at all. I just want the form to submit automatically. I'll keep Googling. The OCD is kicking it lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#form-id...").submit(); // in which event you submit this
```

OR:

```
$("#form-button").trigger('click'); // the form is automatically submit
```

Comment: Thanks. I need `form.find('button.form_button_submit').on('click', function() { `  and `form.find('button.form_button_save').on('click', function()` to happen on load and without clicking.

Comment: maybe needs `$(document).ready(function(){` instead of `new function($)`?

Comment: reposted as I narrowed down issue